# TRASFERR DATA FROM TABLE

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that extracts a whole series of data with progressives from a fact01 table.
now i would like this data to be transferred into fact 02, so that when i make select * from fact.02 i have all the data.

1 option
insert these data in a temporary table ,
insert everything in fact 02.
2 option
or read from the select and via a while loop insert all records

Comment: you could provide more specific details about the data, where the data is coming from and how it is stored.